# Vuetify v-select does not support keyboard tab key

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I have the form below for users. The issue here is when I am on first_name field and I press tab key on the keyboard it takes me to the last_name field. When I press tab key when I am on last_name field it skips the city field and goes directly to the phone_number field. I have to click on city field to select the city. Tab key doesn't take me to v-select. I am using vuetify version 2.3.10. I am not able to figure out a work around for this. Any idea how this can be resolved?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-form :model='user'>
      <v-text-field
       label='First Name'
       v-model='user.first_name'>
      </v-text-field>
      <v-text-field
       label='Last Name'
       v-model='user.last_name'>
      </v-text-field>
      <v-select 
       :items="cities"
       attach
       item-text='name'
       item-value='name'
       v-model="user.city"
       label="City">
      </v-select>
      <v-text-field
       label='Phone Number'
       v-model='user.phone_number'>
      </v-text-field>
    </v-form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Here it works without problem https://codepen.io/MNSY22/pen/MWbgNjK

Comment: @Mohsen it doesn't. Please try switching fielding using tab key. It doesn't work in your codepen too.

Answer (score 1):

`v-select` logically is `text` input, and the opened list is `v-list-item`, so if you want the list open on focus you have to add code like this to your `v-select`

```
<v-select 
  @focus="($event) => {$event.target.click()}"
<v-select
```

Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MNSY22/pen/MWbgNjK)

Comment: Mohsen this is not the issue, The issue which is the skips the v-select field for city and goes directly to v-text-field for phone number on pressing the tab button on the keyboard when I am on last_name field

Comment: I guess the problem is from your system, here is going to v-select when I press tab button, I can't see any problem, try on another pc

Comment: in the codepen, you have added clicked method. are you using it somewhere?

Comment: First, i put `@focus="clicked($event)"`. later, changed `@focus` to call it inline

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem because I had followed the advice in [this issue thread](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6275#issuecomment-546621371) earlier on.
By setting the v-select's input style to `display: none`, the browser no longer focuses on it with the tab key.

The fix is to use the following styles instead, which set the input's width to 0 instead of hiding it completely:

```css
.v-select__selections input {
    width: 0 !important;
    max-width: 0 !important;
}
.v-select__selections .v-select__selection {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only `@focus="$event.target.click()"` in focus event. It works for me.

```
<v-select
    label="Choose Item"
    v-model="item_id"
    :items="items"
    item-text="name"
    item-value="id"
    @focus="$event.target.click()">
</v-select>
```